# Finite union of open sets

Tags: real-analysis

I have clearly understood that the arbitrary/countable union of open sets is open. But is this true for finite union of open sets?  specifically, will $(a,b)\cup(c,d)$ be an open set?

Comment: "finite" is among "arbitrary"

Comment: finite is also countable

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $A \cup B$ is not open for open sets $A$ and $B$.

By definition, then, there is some point $x$ in $A \cup B$ that has no neighborhood contained in $A \cup B$.

But since $x$ must be in $A$ or $B$ or both, then it has a neighborhood contained in its corresponding parent set.

Thus, the neighborhood is in $A \cup B$.

Answer (score 1):

if it is true for a countable union it will surely be true for a finite union just think of the finite union repeated infinitely many often.

In that case you have the same union and you can apply your rule

Answer (score 1):

The empty set is open. Hence you can write
$$A\cup B= A\cup B \cup \emptyset \cup \emptyset \cup ...$$
And the right hand side is open since it is an Arbitrary/countable union of open sets